# FileSystemWatcher stops detecting changes c#

Tags: c#, .net, io, filesystemwatcher

I have a file system watcher set up to process/move files that are dumped in a location.  The first few times I run it, it works great, then it randomly stops detecting file changes.  What could cause this?  I'll post my code below.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        fileSystemWatcher1.Path = Config.ToString("WATCHPATH");
        //ignore subfolder changes (error and archive)

        fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = false;

        //add event handlers
        fileSystemWatcher1.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        fileSystemWatcher1.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        fileSystemWatcher1.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);
        fileSystemWatcher1.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        //begin watching
        fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileAttributes attr;
            try
            {
                attr = File.GetAttributes(e.FullPath);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfEx)
            {
                //this is here because after you move the file to the archive folder
                //it triggers a change, and can't find the old file.  This ignores changes
                //in subdirectories after moves from main drop folder
                return;
            }

            //this checks if a path is a directory which eliminates circular events being triggered
            if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
            {
                return;
            }
            FileProcessor fp = new FileProcessor();
            fp.Process(e.FullPath);

            DirectoryInfo parentDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(e.FullPath);
            string archivePath = parentDirectory.FullName + "\\Archive\\" + Settings._sys.User.UserID + "_" + DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("ddMMMMyyyy") + "_" + e.Name;

            if (!Directory.Exists(parentDirectory.FullName + "\\Archive"))
            {
                //create archive directory
                Directory.CreateDirectory(parentDirectory.FullName + "\\Archive");
            }

            //appends number to file if the filename already exists
            if (File.Exists(archivePath))
            {
                string pathOnly = archivePath.Substring(0, archivePath.LastIndexOf('\\'));
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pathOnly, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(archivePath) + "*" + Path.GetExtension(archivePath));
                int x = files.Max(f => GetFileNumber(f)) + 1;
                string fileNameNoExt = e.Name.Substring(0, e.Name.IndexOf("."));
                archivePath = parentDirectory.FullName + "\\Archive\\" + Settings._sys.User.UserID + "_" + DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("ddMMMMyyyy") + "_" + fileNameNoExt + "_" + x.ToString() + ".xlsx";
            }

            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            try
            {
                while (IsFileReady(e.FullPath) != true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for file to be released by process");
                    continue;
                }
                File.Move(e.FullPath, archivePath);
                File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(archivePath, DateTime.UtcNow);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
//log error
            }
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            string msg = string.Format("File {0} | {1}",
                                       e.FullPath, e.ChangeType);
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
//logs error
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'd better also subscribe the Error event, this code is unlikely to not cause a problem.

Comment: did the program crash?

Comment: Add a log entry before your first `try` just to make *sure* it's not detecting changes. If it writes to the log each time, at least you've eliminated the filewatcher change event not being raised, and can actually troubleshoot your code - which seems to be fine at first glance, by the way.

Comment: I added logging as the first line of the OnChanged Event.  For my test, I dropped a file into the watch path, waited for it to process, then dropped the next file in (clone of the original file).  It processed the first 4 files, but didn't even trigger the logging on the 5th file.  I tried to increase the InternalBufferSize of the fileSystemWatcher to it's max (64kb), but I'm still seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

This part of the code looks critical

```
        fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        try
        {
            while (IsFileReady(e.FullPath) != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for file to be released by process");
                continue;
            }
```

It could remain in the disabled state till file is not ready...

Comment: the while could continue forever

Comment: Still, this is just a guess

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Note that a FileSystemWatcher may miss an event when the buffer size is exceeded. To avoid missing events, follow these guidelines:
>
> - Increase the buffer size by setting the InternalBufferSize property.
> - Avoid watching files with long file names, because a long file name contributes to filling up the buffer.
> - Consider renaming these files using shorter names.
> - Keep your event handling code as short as possible.

I'd look at the first and last bullets.

It seems to me your event handling code is not very short.  It contains a `while` loop that could take some time to complete. Perhaps the event handler should simply add the path to a [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) and exit.  A separate worker process would poll the queue and take appropriate action.

Comment: I experience the same issue. I do not only miss an event. The system completely stop working and I have no error, nothing. It stop each time I remove multiple file. I just want to lags the actions. I do nothing more than logging.